# AngularJs automoplete-alt reset suggestions

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I'm using angularJS with autocomplete-alt. everything works fine but if i clear automoplete input using angularJS function suggestion list isn't updated. How do I reset the suggestion list?

I've tried to use this command `$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput');` without any success.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete which has it already built in, and expects html to be passed to the client, which would make it a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this problem myself. I just had to trigger input change event after setting new value like that:

```
var e = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
e.value = "";
var $e = angular.element(e);
$e.triggerHandler('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput');

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the scope of the angucomplete element:

```
var ngAutoCompleteElement = elem.find('angucomplete-alt');
var ngAutoCompleteScope = ngAutoCompleteElement.isolateScope();
ngAutoCompleteScope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput');
```

Or using the rootScope with the element id suggested in this enhancement [clear angucomplete-alt after button click](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt/issues/60)

```
$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput', 'idOfAutocompleteElement');
```